# PostgreSQL is there a way to average results to a limited number of end results?

Tags: postgresql

Let me try to explain what I mean by example:

I am using PostgreSQL version 9.2.1

Data is structured as follows:

```
(timedate)date           | (float) data    |  ...
"2013-03-23 03:58:00-04" | 66819.59        |  ...
"2013-03-23 03:59:00-04" | 64277.22        |  ...
"2013-03-23 03:59:00-04" | 46841.75        |  ...
"2013-03-23 04:00:00-04" | 69697.38        |  ...
"2013-03-23 04:00:00-04" | 69452.69        |  ...
"2013-03-23 04:01:00-04" | 69697.47        |  ...
```

My table has over 5 million data points. I already know how to grab data within the range of a start and end date.

**Here is my problem**: When the range is too big, say it ranges over the entire data it will return all the 5 million rows, I want to LIMIT the rows it returns without omitting any data.

For example if I want to return 5 rows I want the first row be the average of the data of the first million rows. The second rows the average of the data of the second million rows and so on.(Obviously this example is a bit extreme and I just exaggerated to try and convey what I need to do)

Thank you for your help and advice!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the day average:

```
select
    date_trunc('day', "date")::date "day",
    avg("data") "data"
from t
group by 1
order by 1
```

Change `'day'` for `'month'` or `'week'` as you like.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

If you really want to divide the data in 5 chunks ordered by date:

```
select
    floor(
        (row_number() over(order by "date"))::double precision
        * 5
        / (select count(*) from t)
    ) chunk,
    avg("data") "data"
from t
group by 1
order by 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, you have to excuse me I am not an expert in postgreSQL. Could you explain what the part after the date_trunc() function does? ::date "day"

Comment: @Philipp `::date` casts the result of `date_trunc` from timestamp to date. `"day"` is the alias given to that column in the result set.